# v-if is not working in my child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to show a span whenever v-if is equal to true in my child component. Could anyone advice what I did wrong. Currently, I have no idea what I did incorrectly.

**Child Component**

```
const cardsTemplate = {
    template: 
    `
        <fieldset v-if="show.seach_checkboxes">
            <span>HELLO WORLD</span>
        </fieldset>
    `,
    props: ['js_local'],
    data() {
        return {
            show:{
                search_checkboxes : {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: true,
                }
            }
        }
    },
    methods :{
        change_boolean : function(reverse_boolean){
            this.show[reverse_boolean] = !this.show[reverse_boolean]
            console.log(this.show)
        },
        show_search_template: function(){
            this.change_boolean('search_checkboxes')
        },
        get_search_template : function(){
            $.post(this.js_local.ajaxurl,
                {action : 'get_search_templates'}
            ).done((data)=>{
                this.name = JSON.parse(data)
            }).fail((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
            })
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `data()` with type checking, the same way `props` is used. Try this:

```
data() {
    return {
        show: {
            search_checkboxes: true
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in your template HTML, you've misspelled `search_checkboxes`, it's missing an "r".

```
<fieldset v-if="show.seach_checkboxes">
                         ^^^
```

Comment: I found another issue with your code, added that to my answer. Can you add console output to your question?

Comment: This was a very stupid mistake from me. It works. Thank you!

Comment: I have one more question. Do you know how I can import another component into this component?  I am not using .vue extension files but .js files. I am not using node.js. Just plain html and javascript.

Comment: Check out https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration-in-a-Module-System

Comment: However, I am not using module system. So, I cannot do import ... from ...